# Proper way to use gmail as a email backend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail

I'm hosting all my apps on GCP, and some of these apps using my Gmail account as a email backend.

However, my google account turns off "allow less secure app" automatically after some while.

Why are apps hosting by GCP considered "less secure" (GCP account is the same with Gmail account)?

How can I make my apps "more secure apps"?

BTW, some of the apps are Django app, and some are Node.js app.

---

Most of these apps are for work, and I'm using my work Gmail. So there won't be too much traffic.

Comment: Gmail has a sending limit of 2000 messages per day (500 for a trial account).  Maybe consider using some other provider.

Answer (score 0):

If an user has previously opted to let Less Secure Apps access their account, but no Less Secure Apps have connected to their account in some time, Google will turn this account-level setting off for them.

A less secure app (LSA) is an app that connects to Google accounts using only username and password verification for access and not OAuth. Generally, you should only allow your users to use external apps that connect to Google accounts via **[OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)** to make apps more secure, as LSAs make user accounts more vulnerable.

Whenever possible, users should connect to their accounts via OAuth, a more secure method. OAuth allows third-party apps to use Google account information without seeing a user’s password, and it gives admins security controls like the ability to whitelist certain apps and offer scope-based account access.

Refer to the [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=) for more information about LSA.

Comment: Google has turned off Less Secure Apps for an application that was actively sending email (a contact form handler on my website). Office 365 also does this. Google/Microsoft should at least send an email notifying customers that it is changing settings due to XYZ.